# Cant return from inside a map

Tags: javascript, return

I'm trying to return two results from within a map to the containing function, but it always returns an undefined result, I think maybe happens because it return to the arrow function instead of the main one but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

```
let nums          = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 21, 42, 3]
let target        = 22
let numerodearray = -1

calculator()

function calculator(i, j) 
  {
  nums.map((item) => 
    {
    numerodearray  = numerodearray + 1
    let loopmaximo = nums.length
    for (let i = numerodearray; i < loopmaximo; i++) 
      {
      let comparator = nums[i]
      if (item + comparator == target) 
        {
        console.log(item)
        console.log(comparator)
        return [item, comparator]
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

i was expecting that the function will receive those two values but it doesn't and i am not sure why.

Comment: Map transforms each item into a new array

Comment: The map-callback has a `return` statement, your `calculator` does not have a `return` statement. So return what `map` returns.

Comment: You must put `;` on endings, and avoid working in Sloppy mode...

Comment: `map` is probably the wrong method to use here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. The purpose of `.map` is to create a new array, with each element of the array being computed by calling the inner function. If that's what you're trying to do, then at least you'll need to assign that array to a variable. For example:

```
const mappedArray = nums.map((item) => {
  // ...
});
console.log(mappedArray)
```

Note that `mappedArray` will be an array with length 10 (since that's the length of `nums`, and each element of the array is either an array or undefined (since that's what the inner function returns)

```js
let nums = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 21, 42, 3];
let target = 22;
let numerodearray = -1;

calculator();

function calculator(i, j) {
  const mappedArray = nums.map((item) => {
    numerodearray = numerodearray + 1;
    let loopmaximo = nums.length;
    for (let i = numerodearray; i < loopmaximo; i++) {
      let comparator = nums[i];
      if (item + comparator == target) {
        return [item, comparator];
      }
    }
  });
  console.log(mappedArray);
}
```

---

If that's not what you had in mind, please tell us more about what your goal is.